# Perl odd behaviour, in-script declared variable and <STDIN> fetched variable difference

Tags: perl

I have this script, works ok:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$key = pack("H*","3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cd");

$str = "&4\=80CHB'";
$dec = decode($str);
print "Decoded string value: $dec\n";

sub decode{ #Sub to decode
    @subvar=@_;
    my $sqlstr = $subvar[0];
    $cipher = unpack("u", $sqlstr);
    $plain = $cipher^$key;
    return substr($plain, 0, length($cipher));
}
```

If I alter it to get the $str variable from STDIN, it messes up all the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$key = pack("H*","3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cd");

print "Enter string to decode: ";
$str=<STDIN>;chomp $str;
$dec = decode($str);
print "Decoded string value: $dec\n";

sub decode{ #Sub to decode
    @subvar=@_;
    my $sqlstr = $subvar[0];
    $cipher = unpack("u", $sqlstr);
    $plain = $cipher^$key;
    return substr($plain, 0, length($cipher));
}
```

First script gets it ok, result is:

> Decoded string value: mentos

Second script is bad:

> Decoded string value: ot&¸ÝÖóvë½vÍ

Any idea on what I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You original code has

```
$str = "&4\=80CHB'";
```

which for some reason contains an escaped equals sign. It is the same as

```
$str = "&4=80CHB'";
```

so you need to enter `&4=80CHB'` to your modified code.

Comment: My sting needs to have "\" and other special characters, how can I escape them to keep them unaltered as I send them from STDIN? Something with \Q....\E ???

Comment: @xtmtrx, Your string does not contain "\". The string literal `"&4\=80CHB'"` produces the string `&4=80CHB'`. If you want the string `&4\=80CHB'`, you need to use the literal `"&4\\=80CHB'"`.

Comment: You can use single quotes (or the `q` operator) like `'ABC\123'` which represents the characters ABC\123. Your string above could be coded as `q(&4\=80CHB')`. You can use any printable character as the delimiters for `q`, but if the last character is a backslash you *always* have to double it up, like `q|ABC\123\\|` for ABC\123\.